# "What should I do when someone answers my question?" Post something about Java/C++?

Tags: bug

When I go to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it says:

> The designers of Java explicitly rejected the idea of friend as it works in C++. You put your "friends" in the same package. Private, protected, and packaged security is enforced as part of the language design...

Maybe something was copied/pasted on the wrong place? :-)